# Sympy: "propagate" conjugate into sum

Tags: sympy

Is there a way to "propagate" a conjugate into a sum?

```
from sympy import *

k = symbols('k', cls=Idx)
K = symbols('K', type=Integer)
g = IndexedBase('g')
omega = symbols('\omega', real=True)

s = summation(exp(I*omega*k)*g[k], (k,0,K))
sconj=s.conjugate()
```

Now `sconj` is

[image: Summation with conjugate]

How can I turn this expression into the one below? That is, apply the conjugate on the terms rather than the sum.

[image: Summation with conjugate of the terms]

(Which I off course can obtain by taking the conjugate of the terms when creating the summation

```
summation((exp(I*omega*k)*g[k]).conjugate(), (k,0,K))
```

but think of the general case where this may be not so straightforward.)

Comment: What kind of general case do you have in mind? You sum over a valid sympy expression, which always has a `conjugate` attribute. Can you provide an example where your code would not work?

Comment: I figured out the problem. If I set ``real=true`` on ``K`` it works as expected and the conjugate above the sum moves into the sum. It's good to use the source sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into this.

It is required to set the summation bound as Real, so changing the definition of `K` to

```
K = symbols('K', type=Integer, real=True)
```

did the trick.